# Setting read_data after calling mock.mock_open()

Tags: python-3.x, mocking, python-unittest

I am testing a class that in turn uses `open`. I want to patch `open` on the test **class** for simplicity, but set `read_data` per test. So something like this:

```py
@mock.patch('builtins.open', unittest.mock.mock_open())
class test_TheClassUnderTest:
  def test_MakeSureAMethodWorks(self):
     open().read_data = "custom data for the test"
```

I confirmed that tests work when I set `read_data` in the patch decorator:

```py
@mock.patch('builtins.open', unittest.mock.mock_open(read_data="acid burn and zero cooooooool"))
class test_TheClassUnderTest(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_MakeSureAMethodWorks(self):
     # ...
     self.assertEquals(object.a_method(), expected_value)
```

I've tried setting the return values of the mock returned from `open()`:

```py
open().read.return_value = "custom data for the test"
open().readline.return_value = "custom data for the test"
```

but it's not working. Is there a way to set the value of `read_data` after the `mock_open()` constructor has been called or, more generally, another way to do this?

Comment: Your second try (`open().read.return_value = "..."`) should actually work - I just tested it. You just call `with open(...)` in `a_method`, right?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to mock the `.return_value` for `open().read`. Use `mock_open(read_data="fake data")` is enough.

E.g.

`main.py`:

```py
def main(file_path):
    lines = []
    with open(file_path) as f:
        for line in f:
            lines.append(line)
        return lines
```

`test_main.py`:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import mock_open, patch
from main import main


class TestMain(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_main(self):
        m = mock_open(read_data="custom data for the test\nsecond line")
        with patch('builtins.open', m) as mocked_open:
            actual = main('fake/file/path')
            self.assertEqual(actual, ['custom data for the test\n', 'second line'])
            mocked_open.assert_called_once_with('fake/file/path')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

test result:

```
⚡  coverage run /Users/dulin/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/python-codelab/src/stackoverflow/65533628/test_main.py && coverage report -m --include='./src/**'
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.010s

OK
Name                                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
src/stackoverflow/65533628/main.py            6      0   100%
src/stackoverflow/65533628/test_main.py      12      0   100%
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                                        18      0   100%
```